# What is the official end of support date for Internet Explorer 6 on Windows XP?

Tags: internet-explorer-6

If I read the docs on [Windows Service Pack support policies](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/#servicepacksupport), and the [specific Internet Explorer lifecycle support page](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps#Internet_Explorer) as well as the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6#Supported_platforms) I've deduced that:

IE6 support ends/ended at:

- Windows 2000

  - Ended (date unknown)
- Windows XP

  - SP0 (RTM) Ended

    - Home: 30-Aug-2003
    - Pro: 30-Sep-2004
  - SP1 Ended

    - Home: 11-Jul-2004
    - Pro: 11-Jul-2004
  - SP2

    - Home: 13-Jul-2010
    - Pro: 13-Jul-2010
  - SP3 (released: April 21, 2008)

    - Home: ???
    - Pro: ???

What isn't clear is the ***Windows XP SP3*** scenario.

In "human" terms, when is the end of support for IE6 on Windows XP SP3?

I realize this doesn't force people to upgrade to a newer browser however I'm trying to get a "semi" official word on when IE6 moves into the "not supported" category.

I'm not interested in philosophical answers e.g. "big enterprise won't upgrade but they will expect support into 2017" stuff... I just want the "clear answer" in terms of official Microsoft support.

Comment: I can't help you, but to convince people don't forget to mention the declining support by the internet community -- http://www.ie6nomore.com/ and the like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears as though it's April 2014. I looked [here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-gb&C2=1173), and it wasn't too helpful, but from my cursory googling, it seems to be April 2014.

**EDIT**: I believe that *standard support* has ended, and XP SP3 is in *extended support* phase right now. This *extended support* phase ends in April 2014.

Comment: Trivia: IE 5.01 on Win2000 was supported until 2010 for the same reason!